# MERN app deployed on Ubuntu server with Nginx and PM2 only works when connected to VPN GUI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, deployment, mern

My first time deploying any app so excuse my basic question.
I have developed a MERN app and deployed it on an Ubuntu server using Nginx and PM2. This Ubuntu server is basically a machine that was set up by a friend of mine so there is no hosting service involved. The app runs successfully on both the IP address and domain. However, the app only works when I am connected to the VPN GUI that is connected to the virtual server machine. Once I disconnect from VPN GUI,my app stops working and the IP address no longer displays the app.
Can someone guide me on this issue? I have attached my Nginx configuration file and firewall settings for reference:
Let me know if you want to see any other information.
Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /Workspace2022/condo_control/condo_control_frontend/build;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name coderswibetio.com *.coderswibetio.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Firewall settings:

```
22/tcp ALLOW IN Anywhere
80/tcp ALLOW IN Anywhere
443 ALLOW IN Anywhere
22/tcp (v6) ALLOW IN Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6) ALLOW IN Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6) ALLOW IN Anywhere (v6)
```

Let me know if you want to see any other information.